# Estimating risk aversion (power or exponential utility) from options prices

Tags: options, risk-neutral

I came across this literature and it seems like there are a number of ways people do this. You can do it for an option on any underlying as long as you can create the risk-neutral p.d.f. 
If you agree with a particular estimation method please share why and how you would use your estimates in action. More importantly, how do you interpret your estimates for different underlying assets?